# messed up .htaccess [R=301,L]

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I think i've messed up my .htaccess

I was playing around to get my permalinks right, and now when i wanted to reset it back to normal localhost. it doesn't work as usual. I had to write "localhost/index.php" or "127.0.0.1" to open the usual "localhost" instead. How do i fix this?

I was using this then it all started to go wrong, even when i type any jibberish after "RewriteEngine On". typing "localhost" doesn't bring up the page error, unless if it type "localhost/index.php" or "127.0.0.1":

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^\.
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

If i want to reset it all back to normal (just type localhost and it will automatically bring up to my localhost index.php). Do i have to set back the httpd.conf file to default? If so, where can i get the default httpd.conf file for apache 2.4.2?

Comment: just remove the file .htacess

Comment: Did you lose a `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html` somewhere along the way?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: I didn't touch the httpd.conf file at all.
I've checked and it's still as usual ->
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
</IfModule>

Comment: @Wololo: Nah, didn't work.

Comment: @AFwcxx Check if *dir_module* has been unloaded - *a2ctl -M | grep dir*